# wordpress and hardcoded domain names in URL

Tags: wordpress

I just installed Wordpress, and one thing I discovered is that site URL appears to be hardcoded in all the generated HTML.

For example, I see things like:

```
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.mywebserver.com/wp-    content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css" />
<link rel="pingback" href="http://www.mywebserver.com/xmlrpc.php" />
```

Is there a way to tell Wordpress to strip out the domain name in the generated URLs?  For example, I would prefer:

```
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css" />
<link rel="pingback" href="/xmlrpc.php" />
```

Comment: You may find this discussion very interesting. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-relative-instead-of-absolute-links-for-images?replies=19

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple links of code can fix it, in your functions file and header file: [Fix absolute links in Wordpress](http://mikevoermans.com/php/set-wordpress-urls-to-be-root-relative-throughout-your-site)

**Functions.php**

```
function fix_links($input) {
return preg_replace('!http(s)?://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/!', '/', $input);
}
```

**Header.php** -- before you output any HTML

```
ob_start('fix_links');
```

Comment: I had to modify this in two ways: one add <?php ob_end_flush(); ?> to the end of the footer (good practice), and change $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] to the Wordpress host function site_url() e.g. return (str_replace(site_url(), "", $input)); as I am proxying the site and SERVER_NAME returns the proxy host rather than Wordpress host.