# How to change wordpress css file and javascript file to relative path?

Tags: wordpress

Currently the path of my css and javascript files are: http://www.domain.com/image/...

How to change the path to simply `/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/background.jpg` ?

Is there any plugin to do it automatically?

Please help!

Comment: Can you clarify what path you want to change where? What are you trying to address from which file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9986335/1679849

Comment: Thanks for replying! I want to change all the css files and javascript files's links. For example: In my header.php, the link use to access css file is "http://www.domain.com/wp-content/../css", but since I change my domain to https, this link does not work, because it is still http and it can not access my css file. I want to change this link just to "/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/..." Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your css & js files are inside theme folder, then just use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri();`. This takes care of http or https. It gives complete path to your files.

ex: `<script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/script.js' ?>"></script>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/css/style.css">
```

Comment: Thanks! What about for the upload images?

Comment: you can use $url = content_url().'/uploads/img.jpg'; like: <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>"/>